# How to check the when internal hard drive connected in the system

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

-- its not duplicate and no answer available for the same, earlier question was asked for USB mass storage..
But the concern is with the internal drives.

Can anyone know the way or software to know at what times the internal drives removed from the system and at what time its reconnected.

After logon is all drives connected at particular time and working or not?
very urgent and importrant question for official and commercial use , for saving the data from copying and etc...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just secure the BIOS with password and manually add the drive and disable all other ports (so no drive can be use). And lock the case. (Locking case might be easier?)

Tons of software, here is a random example: https://www.10-strike.com/networkinventoryexplorer/track-hardware.shtml